# Understanding Google Earth Engine GOES-16 image string

Tags: google-earth-engine, goes-16

I am trying to use the NOAA/GOES/16/MCMIPC for weather analysis in Google Earth Engine (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GOES_16_MCMIPC#description) but I cannot find documentation on how to read/parse the image string:

```
var imageName = '2020211203115800000';
```

So I can select a date range, in particular finding out what images are available.

Comment: @xunilk Thanks. Deleted my wrong suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Running following [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a1d8d0c74b63c51daac3acc48c8ca5e), you can get information about GOES-16 image products. Complete Image Collection has 388,607 images; one for each date (there are multiples images per day). On the other hand, there are 1,361 distinct dates (list begins in 2000-01-01 and ends in 2021-04-12; actual day). You can also observe that this collection can be filtered by dates. Finally, image with 'system:index' equals to '2020211203115800000' (from your question) is filtered by Metadata properties and its associated date is also obtained (2020-07-29T20:31:15).

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/GOES/16/MCMIPC");

print("size of all collection", collection.size());

var allDates = ee.List(collection.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

print("size of all dates", allDates.size());

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0, 10);
  }).distinct();

print("size of all distinct dates", allDatesSimple.size());

print("list of all distinct dates", allDatesSimple);

var new_coll = collection
  .filterDate('2017-07-10', '2017-07-11');

print("new collection filterd by date", new_coll);

var img = collection
  .filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals', '2020211203115800000')
  .first();

print("image with id 2020211203115800000", img);

print("date of image id 2020211203115800000", ee.Date(img
  .get('system:time_start')).format());
```

Comment: Thanks xunilk, will try this one and hopefully I will understand this better.